# Instantiate a value received from issuing a GET request

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

I have this JS code, that will receive a string value, from the C# code

```
function getMsg() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "andSert.asmx/GetMessage", true); //async

var temp = the string I receive from the GET above

return temp;
```

}

Here is the C# code

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetMessage() {
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (Global.sAppPath + "/alt/importantMsg.xml");

    string message = null;

    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.IsStartElement ()) {
            switch (reader.Name.ToString ()) {

            case "Message":
                message = reader.ReadString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to instantiate the message I get from doing a GET request in the JS code. I have tested that everything works, and returns a string. But I need to instantiate that string, so that I can use it in another JS file.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you are using an async request then you wont be able to return the value as you wont have the string before the return statement is executed

Comment: Ok, I'll change that to false, so it's sync

Comment: Can you use jQuery ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar, how exactly would you block the rest of the function?

Comment: Yes I guess I could, if I will not find the solution using pure JS :)
In that case, then I know how to solve it. But this system uses this approach entirely, so starting to throwing in JQuery will make the code even drift away from how it is now. I will also need to get the libraries etc

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using jQuery $.ajax instead as it shields you from browser quirks.

Synchronous solution:

```
function getMsg() {
  var msg = "";
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    { 
      msg = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).d;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","andSert.asmx/GetMessage",false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  xmlhttp.send();
  return msg;
}
```

Async solution:

```
function getMsg(fCallback) {
  var msg = "";
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      fCallback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).d);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","andSert.asmx/GetMessage",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
getMsg(function(message) { alert(message); });
```

Also the service has to be properly decorated:

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Whatever {
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  [ScriptService]
  public class andSert : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetMessage() {
      return "Hello World";
    }
  }
}
```

Note the classes should have names like `class MyFavouriteClass`, using `class andSert` to match your question.

Comment: The xmlhttp.responseText returns "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="http://scandiatransplant.org">This is a test</string>" I only want to show the value say "This is a test". I guess I could get this value by using string.split, but this is a very ugly solution. Is there another way I can get this value alone?

Comment: @user1960836 - decorate your C# method with [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)] attribute

Comment: I added this [WebMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] and getting an error, saying WebMethodAttribute does not contain a definition for UseHttp. Looking up the WebMethod and its attributes, UseHttp is not one of them. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @user1960836 - I said ScriptMethod, not WebMethod :)

Comment: That didn't fix it, I'm still getting the string with xml tags. What is the [WebMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] do in this context? From what I understand by reading the doc,it will just force the method only to be called with a get?

Comment: @user1960836 - for clarity sake I've edited my answer, hopefully you should be all set.